Python Turtle - Fullscreen Background with the sun in the middle and palm tree silhouettes
I attempted to recreate a background using the code below, but I am unsure how I can recreate the background image below. I was able to get the correct colours and the yellow sun in the middle, however, I am not sure how I can do the other parts of the background image.
Background with the sun and palm tree sillhouettes
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.colormode(255)

for x in range(0,67):
    turtle.color(154+x,x,254-x)
    turtle.goto(0,67-x)
    turtle.goto(67,67-x)

for x in range(0,55):
    turtle.color(221,67+x,187-x)
    turtle.goto(0,0-x)
    turtle.goto(67,0-x)

for x in range(0,52):
    turtle.color(221,122,132-x)
    turtle.goto(0,-55-x)
    turtle.goto(67,-55-x)


turtle.fillcolor("yellow")
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.goto(0,0)
turtle.color("yellow")
turtle.circle(100)

turtle.end_fill()



With difficulty.  The image is not meant for turtle.  The gradiant-fill background might be faked with 1 pixel-wide lines of slowly varying color.  The tree fronds are 1 shape mirrored, rotated, and scaled.  The triangle 'teeth' are only tedious. The smooth 'back' of varying curvature might need 100 short straight lines to fake.  The situation is similar for the trunks.

How accurate do you need the drawing to be?  A sincere approximation, perhaps?
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

COLOR = (0.60156, 0, 0.99218)
TARGET = (0.86328, 0.47656, 0.31250)

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 950, 530

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.tracer(False)

deltas = [(hue - COLOR[index]) / HEIGHT for index, hue in enumerate(TARGET)]

def tree(length, order):
    if length >= length / order:
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(45)
        tree(length / 2, length / order)
        turtle.right(90)
        tree(length / 2, length / order)
        turtle.left(45)
        turtle.backward(length)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.color(COLOR)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2)
turtle.pendown()

direction = 1

for distance, y in enumerate(range(HEIGHT//2, -HEIGHT//2, -1)):

    turtle.forward(WIDTH * direction)
    turtle.color([COLOR[i] + delta * distance for i, delta in enumerate(deltas)])
    turtle.sety(y)

    direction *= -1

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(0, -HEIGHT/2)
turtle.color("goldenrod")

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(240)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.color('black')
turtle.goto(-WIDTH/2, -HEIGHT/2)
turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.goto(-WIDTH/2, -HEIGHT/5)

while True:
    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(WIDTH/2, -HEIGHT/5))
    turtle.circle(randint(-120, 120), randint(15, 35))
    if turtle.xcor() > WIDTH/2:
        break

turtle.goto(WIDTH/2, -HEIGHT/2)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.setheading(90)
turtle.goto(-WIDTH / 3, -HEIGHT/3)
turtle.pendown()
tree(150, 8)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(WIDTH / 3, -HEIGHT/3)
turtle.pendown()
tree(150, 8)

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()



Thank you so much I was struggling with this. Don't worry so much about the accuracy, I appreciate your help! I don't think you can make palm trees with turtle code or can you?

@LouisLam, you can draw pretty much anything you want with turtle if you're willing to take the time to think about the problem in a turtle-like fashion.
